# How to change coordinates of label

Tags: c#

After how i did

```
Label label = new Label();
```

i wanna change it location.

I used

```
 label.Location = new Point(190, 190);
 label.Refresh();
 label.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(100, 200);
```

but on windows forms nothing not changed.

Comment: you need to refresh the parent where this label is contained.

Comment: Did you add the label the the Controls collection of a parent?

Comment: But if you _create_ a new label then this label should be added to the parent Controls container to be shown. Instead if you change an _existing_ label then I don't understand what is the purpose of _new Label()_ above

Comment: @AviadHasidof how can i do it?

Comment: @OguzOzgul How can i do it?

Comment: @Steve Sry , but i didnt work with it before and dont understand it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should do that:

```
var lbl1 = new Label();
lbl1.Text = "ddd";
lbl1.Location = new Point(0,0);
Controls.Add(lbl1);
```

you need to add the new label that you created on runtime to a container.
in this case i am adding it to the list of controls under the form.
When you change the location it will be reflected.